# Firebase queries not calling block when there are no results

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using Firebase and I want to query to see if something exists. It gets called when a value is found, but the block does not get called when nothing is found. Is this expected behaviour?

```
    ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqualToValue(channelName).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print("found channel:  \(snapshot.key)")
        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
        print(error.description)
    })
```

Have I done something wrong? Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you got rid of querying and simply used observe and checked for snapshot.exists()? The answer below doesn't use querying though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check for no data (snapshot == NULL) it's done this way

```
    let refToCheck = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath(channelNameString)
    refToCheck.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("snapshot was NULL")
        } else {
            print(snapshot)
        }
    })
```

Queries are pretty heavy by comparison to the .observeEventType and since you already know the specific path you are checking for it will perform much better.

Edit: You can also use

```
if snapshot.exists() { ... }
```

Firebase queries are best used when you want to retrieve child nodes that contain specific values or a range of values.

**Edit for Firebase 3.x and Swift 3.x**

```
    let refToCheck = myRootRef.child(channelNameString)
    refToCheck.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("found the node")
        } else {
            print("node doesn't exist")
        }
    })
```

Note 1) the logic was changed a bit as we now leverage .exists to test for existence of a snapshot.
Note 2) this code leaves an observer active in Firebase so if the node is created at a later time, it will fire.

If you want to check for a node and don't want to leave an observer watching for that node do this:

```
    let refToCheck = myRootRef.child(channelNameString)
    refToCheck.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("found the node")
        } else {
            print("node doesn't exist")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Not working for me. In a scenario where the channelNameString child doesn't exist in the DB

Comment: @kanishka I just coded up a quick test with the exact code from above, copy and paste into my project. I let channelNameString = "no_node" (which does't exist) and ran the code. The output was 'snapshot was NULL'. So the code works. The issue must lie elsewhere. Perhaps a new question with your code and a snippet of your Firebase structure would reveal the issue.

Comment: Yup. It was a permission issue on the DB. Thanks

Comment: @kanishka What was your permission that you changed? I cannot get the callback to trigger when the path doesn't exist.

Comment: This is working if you use a `.value` event. What about if you keep `. childAdded `? The completion is never fired.

Comment: @Nico .childAdded events *only* fire when a child exists so they cannot be used for testing *if* a child exists. You need to use .value for that.

Comment: @Jay I was using `.value` but because I might create new children on new paths offline, I'm switching to `.addedChild` as `.value`'s callback wasn't triggered. So it's good practice to just call `.value` to check an existing path and then use `.addedChild` to retrieve them?

Comment: @Nico It's totally dependent on your use case. Calling .value loads everything in a node; all parents, all children, and can become unwieldy with large datasets. .childAdded iterates over each child and is often more manageable but can't be used to test of the absence of data. It sounds like you have a use case and your question(s) may be better suited as a separate question instead of in comments here. Also note I updated my answer with more details and updated code.